# Keep only a specific portion that is between brackets and remove all the other ones

Tags: regex, literals

I want to remove everything between [] and ()

Samples:
ST Action Issue 08 (1988-12)(GollnerPublishing Ltd)
ST Magazine 070 (1993-03)(La Terre du Milieu)(fr)
20000 Leagues Under The Sea (1988)(Coktel Vision)[cr Big 4]
A Day at the Races (1989)(Team)(Disk 1 of 2)[cr MCA]

My regex :`[^a-zA-Z\s\d][\d-()A-Za-z\] ]+`

It works, the only catch is that I need to keep this one: (Disk 1 of 2). So in the last example, that would be something like this: A Day at the Races (Disk 1 of 2)

I can't find a way to exclude `(Disk 1 of 2)` (ie 'Don't match') and integrate it in the whole expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage a negative lookahead `(?![([]Disk 1 of 2[\])])` that will avoid matching `(Disk 1 of 2)` or `[Disk 1 of 2]`:

```
(?![([]Disk 1 of 2[\])])(?:\([^()]*\)|\[[^\][]*])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fH7uX0/1)

The `(?:\([^()]*\)|\[[^\][]*])` part just matches either a string between round brackets (parentheses) containing no parentheses inside (`\([^()]*\)`) or (`|`) a string inside square brackets containing no square brackets inside (`\[[^\][]*]`).

If `1` and `2` are dynamic and stand for integer numbers, use `\d+`: `(?![([]Disk \d+ of \d+[\])])`

Comment: It works great of course but a bit too much complicated for me. Isn't there an easier way to do it (maybe which would look like more to my original regex)? I seem to only understand the 'Match if suffix is absent' part but then I can't get it to make it work either.

Comment: Maybe you could just let me know the language you are using it in?